# How to adjust Ribbon Commands in OfficeJS Excel

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I was able to add six custom ribbon commands as a single group in Excel add-in. But below are my findings.

1. When I trying to add six commands in a single group getting below attached screen shot which is not expected output.

   [image]
2. But when i trying to make it to seven to adjust the alignment getting below as expected output.

   [image]

3. But with that second point manifest changes if i am trying to upload in online excel, I'm getting

   > Invalid Manifest file error

   due to more ribbon command in a group i believe.
4. But anyway for desktop version there were no issues.

Comment: From you screen shot in #2, it looks like you don't have 7 commands even though you did not get an error. So I think the limit of 6 applies to desktop too. The layout of commands within tab groups is entirely controlled by Office using its algorithms based on the number of commands and the size of the Excel window.

Comment: @RickKirkham...as per screen shot #2 when i added 7 commands in a group then only i got that 6 commands aligned like that screen shot which is expected as we require only 6 commands... but i dont want to add 7th command without which alignment got as per screen shot #1...Kindly advise...Or let me please know if anything i could not make clear...

Comment: @RickKirkham.. Also as i can conclude our requirement is if manifest having 6 commands in a group then screen shot # 1 appears but we wanted to align like in screen shot # 2...can you tell how can achieve required output...

Comment: You can't achieve that. As I mentioned before, you cannot control the layout of the buttons within the tab. Office controls that.